# Given (a, b) compute the maximum value of k such that a^{1/k} and b^{1/k} are whole numbers

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, math

I'm writing a program that tries to find the minimum value of k > 1 such that the kth root of a and b (which are both given) equals a whole number.

Here's a snippet of my code, which I've commented for clarification.

```
int main()
{
    // Declare the variables a and b.
    double a;
    double b;
    // Read in variables a and b.
    while (cin >> a >> b) {

        int k = 2;

        // We require the kth root of a and b to both be whole numbers.
        // "while a^{1/k} and b^{1/k} are not both whole numbers..."
        while ((fmod(pow(a, 1.0/k), 1) != 1.0) || (fmod(pow(b, 1.0/k), 1) != 0)) {

        k++;

        }
```

Pretty much, I read in (a, b), and I start from k = 2 and increment k until the kth roots of a and b are both congruent to 0 mod 1 (meaning that they are divisible by 1 and thus whole numbers).

But, the loop runs infinitely. I've tried researching, and I think it might have to do with precision error; however, I'm not too sure.

Another approach I've tried is changing the loop condition to check whether the floor of a^{1/k} equals a^{1/k} itself. But again, this runs infinitely, likely due to precision error.

Does anyone know how I can fix this issue?

EDIT: for example, when (a, b) = (216, 125), I want to have k = 3 because 216^(1/3) and 125^(1/3) are both integers (namely, 5 and 6).

Comment: With floating point numbers, it is *unreasonable* to test for equality. See http://floating-point-gui.de/

Comment: Why is one return value tested against `1.0` and the other against just `0`?

Comment: Read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ for tips on debugging your code.

Comment: Minimum value of k, or minimum value of 1/k (which corresponds to maximum value of k)? The latter seems more interesting and thus more likely to be the actual problem to be solved.

Comment: (I saw that you deleted your [question about the two integer sum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58150851/finding-two-integers-without-a-zero-digit-that-sum-to-a-target-integer). For what it's worth, I tried to fix my code to handle the counter example you found. Here: https://ideone.com/JKRkqy)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That is not a programming problem but a mathematical one:

> if `a` is a real, and `k` a positive integer, and if `a^(1./k)` is an integer, then `a` is an integer. (otherwise the aim is to toy with approximation error)

So the fastest approach may be to first check if `a` and `b` are integer, then do a [prime decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_factorization) such that a=p<sub>0</sub><sup>e<sub>0</sub></sup> * p<sub>1</sub><sup>e<sub>1</sub></sup> * ..., where p<sub>i</sub> are distinct primes.

Notice that, for a<sup>1/k</sup> to be an integer, each e<sub>i</sub> must also be divisible by k. In other words, k must be a common divisor of the e<sub>i</sub>. The same must be true for the prime powers of b if b<sup>1/k</sup> is to be an integer.

Thus the largest `k` is the [greatest common divisor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_common_divisor) of all e<sub>i</sub> of both `a` and `b`.

---

With your approach you will have problem with large numbers. All IIEEE 754 binary64 floating points (the case of double on x86) have 53 significant bits. That means that all double larger than 2<sup>53</sup> are integer.

The function `pow(x,1./k)` will result in the same value for two different `x`, so that with your approach you will necessary have false answer, for example the numbers 5<sup>5</sup>*2<sup>90</sup> and 3<sup>5</sup>*2<sup>120</sup> are exactly representable with double. The result of the algorithm is `k=5`. You may find this value of `k` with these number but you will also find `k=5` for   5<sup>5</sup>*2<sup>90</sup>-2<sup>49</sup> and 3<sup>5</sup>*2<sup>120</sup>, because pow(5<sup>5</sup>*2<sup>90</sup>-2<sup>49</sup>,1./5)==pow(5<sup>5</sup>*2<sup>90</sup>). Demo [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/288884cc75c39e16)

On the other hand, as there are only 53 significant bits, prime number decomposition of double is trivial.

Answer (score 4):

Floating numbers are *not* mathematical real numbers. The computation is "approximate". See http://floating-point-gui.de/

You could replace the test `fmod(pow(a, 1.0/k), 1) != 1.0` with something like `fabs(fmod(pow(a, 1.0/k), 1) - 1.0) > 0.0000001` (and play with various such  instead of `0.0000001`; see also [std::numeric_limits::epsilon](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/epsilon) but use it carefully, since `pow` might give some error in its computations, and `1.0/k` also inject imprecisions - details are very complex, dive into [IEEE754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) specifications).

Of course, you could (and probably should) define your `bool almost_equal(double x, double y)` function (and use it instead of `==`, and use its negation instead of `!=`).

As a rule of thumb, never test floating numbers for equality (i.e. `==`), but consider instead some small enough *distance* between them; that is, replace a test like `x == y` (respectively `x != y`) with something like `fabs(x-y) < EPSILON` (respectively `fabs(x-y) > EPSILON`) where `EPSILON` is a small positive number, hence testing for a small [L<sub>1</sub> distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxicab_geometry) (for equality, and a large enough distance for inequality).

And avoid floating point in integer problems.

Actually, predicting or estimating floating point accuracy is *very* difficult. You might want to consider tools like [CADNA](https://www-pequan.lip6.fr/cadna//). My colleague Franck Védrine is an expert on static program analyzers to estimate numerical errors (see e.g. his [TERATEC 2017 presentation on Fluctuat](https://www.teratec.eu/library/pdf/forum/2017/Presentations/A8_03_Forum_TERATEC_2017_%20VEDRINE_CEA.pdf)). It is a difficult research topic, see also D.Monniaux's paper [*the pitfalls of verifying floating-point computations*](https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?doid=1353445.1353446) etc.

And floating point errors [did in some cases](http://www-users.math.umn.edu/~arnold//455.f96/disasters.html) cost human lives (or loss of billions of dollars). Search the web for details. There are some cases where *all the digits* of a computed number are wrong (because the errors may accumulate, and the final result was obtained by combining thousands of operations)! There is some indirect relationship with [chaos theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chaos_theory), because many programs might have some [numerical instability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_stability).

Comment: Okay, got it. But just one thing -- shouldn't the loop condition be "fabs(fmod(pow(a, 1.0/k), 1) - 1.0) >= 0.0000001," since we want to keep looping while the statement is not true?

Comment: also in the absolute value, we should be subtracting 0.0 rather than 1.0 right? since they would be congruent to 0 mod 1 ? just making sure...

Comment: It is about computing a distance. You could even use an [euclidean distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance), but then it takes more time to be computed.

Comment: yes. currently, the boolean tests whether the value of fmod(pow(a, 1.0/k), 1) is within epsilon of 1. but shouldn't it be testing whether it's in epsilon of 0? since we want the while condition to evaluate to "false" when they are both integers, which occurs precisely when the kth roots of a and b are equal to 0 mod 1, not 1 mod 1

Comment: You want `fmod(pow(a, 1.0/k), 1)`  (call that `x`) to be sufficiently different of `1.0` (call it `y`). So you want `fabs(x-y)` to be larger than some `EPSILON`

Comment: But then the code breaks when, for example, (a, b) = (5764801, 1679616). It should return k = 4 since the quantities (5764801)^(1/4) and (1679616)^(1/4) are both integers (namely, 49 and 36). However, when we have k = 4, the value of 5764801^(1/4) mod 1 equals 0, and the quantity fabs(x - y) equals 1. Since this value is greater than epsilon, the first boolean expression becomes "true," and the loop goes on forever

Comment: Neither of the two errors in the link you provide were floating-point errors. The first was fixed-point. The second was conversion to a too-narrow integer (for which the source format is irrelevant, as any conversion of a value to a type in which it cannot be represented is an error, regardless of how the source value is represented).

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned, comparing floating point values for equality is problematic. If you find a way to work directly with integers, you can avoid this problem. One way to do so is to raise integers to the `k` power instead of taking the `k`th root. The details are left as an exercise for the reader.